# Trying to get the length of an encrypted string

Tags: c#, encryption, base64, des

I am using the following function to encrypt a string:

```
public string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string SEncryptionKey)
{
try {
    key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Strings.Left(SEncryptionKey, 8));
    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
} catch (Exception e) {
    return e.Message;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is some kind of mathematical algorithm that will allow me to determine, in advance, what the length of the Base64 encrypted string length will be. So if my string is 15 characters long, what will the length of the Base64 encrypted string be?

Comment: Your use of the member `key` is a bit concerning. Also where are your using statements?

Comment: @Jodrell -- I am using both. I am DES encrypting it, then base64 encoding it.

Comment: @ChaosPandion -- Its a work in progress. My "key" is taking the leftmost 8 bytes of the passed in encryption key

Comment: From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

The number of output bytes per input byte is approximately 4 / 3 (33% overhead) and converges to that value for a large number of bytes. More specifically, given an input of n bytes, the output will be bytes long, including padding characters.

Comment: @Jodrell, not sure what your comment about - input string, out *DES*+base64 string. Question could have more simple sample (drop Base64 as its multiplier is known), but even as it is now there is real crypto.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Is the 'concern' that `key` is a public field outside the scope of the method?

Comment: I also think returning an exception message makes the API confusing. Is the caller supposed to write parsing logic to figure out if an error was thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 15 character string will be at least 15 bytes. It could become 20 or even 30 if you have a lot of non-ASCII characters.

The Encryption will round it up to a multiple of the <strike>key</strike> block size, lets say 64 bytes.

Then Base64 goes to encode 8 bit bytes into  6 bit tokens, so you get (64 *  8) / 6 tokens (chars).

Comment: +1. Good catch on UTF8. If knowing size in advance is important - use UTF16 instead... Side question: where(if) DES stores original array size (as it may change final size calculation)?

Comment: The original size will be encrypted too somehow, you won't find it useful.

Comment: 2Henk: You are wrong regarding several things. Block size of DES is 64 bit (not 64 bytes). Also, 8/6 calculation is rough approximation, because Base64 will add padding, if number of encoded bytes isn't divisible by 3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can calculate that.

a) DES encryption uses blocks. As I remember it's 8 bytes. So, if you encrypt anything, it will become rounded to the block sizes.

- As example, you encrypt 1 byte, it will be come 8 bytes.
- You encrypt 8 bytes, it will become 8 bytes
- You encrypt 9 bytes, it will become 16 bytes (minimum amount of block to fit original data)

So, the formale **encryptedLength = ceiling (originalLength /8) * 8**

b) Base64 has also something very similar to block size. And it's block size is 4. Each original 3 bytes will be converted to 4 bytes block

So, for Base64  **encodedLength = ceiling (originalLength/3)*4**

So, the final formula is

**encodedEncryptedLength = ceiling(ceiling(originalLength/8)*8/3)*4**

originalLength here is number of bytes (!!! not characters !!!) in the text which you plan to encrypt.